# sed conditional substitution

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have the file where some of the lines contains dates looking like this

```
2017/07/21=2017/05/23 some text
  somethign
  somthig

2017/04/22=2017/05/23 text2
  smt1
  smt2
```

I would like to change the place of first and second date, but only if first date comes **before** the second.

Is something like that possible using `sed` or some of the other command line linux utilities?

Comment: I find it a bit `awk`ward to state this to somebody with 20.7k reputation, nonetheless : Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: However, to answer your question, yes there exist such tools. `sed` is not really the best way to handle this, but you can achieve this with `awk`.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware that `awk`can do that

Comment: you're welcome. Awk is an extremely powerful tool for record parsing and performing operations on them. Ones you know it, you don't want to change. Because it is that powerful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best tool for the job is `awk`. Awk is a perfect tool for record parsing and field comparisons. The following will do what you expect :

```
awk '/\//&&/=/{ split($1,d,"="); if (d[1] > d[2]) $1 = d[2]"="d[1] }1' <file>
```

and this outputs :

```
2017/05/23=2017/07/21 some text
  somethign
  somthig

2017/04/22=2017/05/23 text2
  smt1
  smt2
```